# Can I synchronize the blockchain on one computer then transfer the files to another?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, backup, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to provide a downloadable blockchain that is updated and verified by a mass of people?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/would-it-be-possible-to-provide-a-downloadable-blockchain-that-is-updated-and-ve)

If I install and synchronize the official Bitcoin wallet, can I backup/transfer it to another computer, so that when I install Bitcoin wallet on the other computer it doesn't have to spend so much time synchronizing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Simplify go into the Bitcoin folder and copy every thing to the new computer. (Make sure you keep wallet.dat safe)